# Heroku cannot find mongoose module after deployment?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I have deployed a simple Nodejs app to Heroku and I keep getting an error in the application logs saying that the module "mongoose" cannot be found. I even provided a relative path instead of just saying require("mongoose"). The deployment succeeds and installs all the dependencies. The source code can be found here https://github.com/collinkleest/trim-io.

Here is the error log from heroku.

```
2020-10-17T02:01:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user collinkleest@gmail.com
2020-10-17T02:01:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-10-17T02:01:59.493929+00:00 app[api]: Deploy af985be5 by user collinkleest@gmail.com
2020-10-17T02:01:59.493929+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user collinkleest@gmail.com
2020-10-17T02:01:59.652847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-10-17T02:02:01.917601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-10-17T02:02:04.175589+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-17T02:02:04.175612+00:00 app[web.1]: > trim-io@0.0.1 start /app
2020-10-17T02:02:04.175612+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-10-17T02:02:04.175613+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369536+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369538+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369539+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369539+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369539+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../node_modules/mongoose'
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369540+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369540+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/models/urlEntity.js
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369541+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369541+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369542+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369542+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369543+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369543+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/models/urlEntity.js:1:18)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369543+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369544+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369544+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369545+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369545+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19) {
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369545+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369546+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/models/urlEntity.js', '/app/server.js' ]
2020-10-17T02:02:04.369546+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-10-17T02:02:04.389361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-10-17T02:02:04.389827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-10-17T02:02:04.398788+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! trim-io@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
2020-10-17T02:02:04.399025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-10-17T02:02:04.399280+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-10-17T02:02:04.399493+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the trim-io@0.0.1 start script.
2020-10-17T02:02:04.399722+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-17T02:02:04.420468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-10-17T02:02:04.420707+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-17T02:02:04.420857+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-17T02_02_04_400Z-debug.log
2020-10-17T02:02:04.487055+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-17T02:02:04.554273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is my server.js for reference as well:

```
const express = require("express");
const UrlEntity = require("./models/urlEntity"); 
const mongoose = require("./node_modules/mongoose");
const urlEntity = require("./models/urlEntity");
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

const mongoUri = "mongodb+srv://" + process.env.MONGO_USR + ":" + process.env.MONGO_PASS + "@" + process.env.MONGO_URL + "/" + process.env.MONGO_DB + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(
    mongoUri,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

async function checkIdExists(id){
    let exists = await UrlEntity.exists({uniqueId: id});
    return exists;
}

function generateId(){
    let randomId = Math.random().toString(20).substr(2, 8);
    while(!(checkIdExists(randomId))){
        randomId = Math.random().toString(20).substr(2, 8);
    }
    return randomId;
}

// redirect functionality 
app.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.id !== null || req.params.id !== undefined){
        let doc = await UrlEntity.findOne({uniqueId: req.params.id});
        res.redirect(doc.targetUrl);
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

// create new url
app.post("/create-url", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("in post");
    let id = generateId();
    await UrlEntity.create({uniqueId: id,
    targetUrl: req.body.url,
    dateCreated: req.body.date});
    res.send(`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/${id}`);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000,  () => {console.log("Trim.io API Started")});
```

Answer (score 1):

You put `mongoose` in your `devDependencies`, which will be removed at runtime. ([Link from your code](https://github.com/collinkleest/trim-io/blob/master/package.json#L23)) You need to move it to `dependencies` so that it will be available at runtime.

Comment: Yep you are right, just noticed that and fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- try changing the `const mongoose = require("./node_modules/mongoose")`
  back to  `const mongoose = require("mongoose");`

---

- Don't forget to set your environment variables ***MONGO_USR***, ***MONGO_PASS*** e.t.c on heroku settings. Your server will not start if the environment variable is not set.
- Lastly I advice you use a connection string like this `mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster2.bftwu.mongodb.net/databaseName`
  without concatenating